# Troubles with images using flashlist in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, flash-list

I have trouble like this: [image: trouble]

The more pictures, the more interference and the longer they last

Does flashlist have a method to display the loading indicator for such cases? If not, how to fix it?
When I use simple flatlist, I dont't have any troubles with this
P.s: I have found onLoad event, but it doesn't work:

```
    <FlashList
        numColumns={2}
        onEndReached={async() => {
          getData()
        }}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        estimatedItemSize={200}
        onLoad={()=>{
          setIsLoading(false)
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-fast-image library to load images quickly and show indicators for each image of the list in the renderItem component.

```
 <FastImage
    style={[
      styles.image,
      {
        width: StyleConfig.smartWidthScale(250),
        height: StyleConfig.smartWidthScale(165),
        backgroundColor: isLoading ? Color.blackOpacity : Color.transparent,
      },
    ]}
    source={{uri:item.image}}
    onLoadStart={() => {
      setLoading(true);
    }}
    onLoadEnd={() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }}
    onError={() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }}>
    {loading && <ActivityIndicator size={'small'} animating={isLoading} />}

  </FastImage>
```

Comment: it doesn't work with expo

Comment: Any library works with Expo, you just have to create a new development build after installing. It doesn't work with Expo Go, though. But the standard Image included with React Native offers the same props: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onloadstart

Additionally, Expo-Image offers similar functionality to react-native-fast-image: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image/